# Type mismatch Run time error-13 in VBA (showing error at Date Variable)

Tags: excel, vba

Here I'm getting error  at

> Dim strDate As Date

as type mismatch run time error..

Please any help will be appreciated....

```
Sub Insert11()

    'click on tools and select Microsoft ActiveX data Objects 2.0 Library
    Dim DBFullName As String
    Dim Connect As String, Source As String
    Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim strDate As Date
    Dim strWeight As Variant
    Dim strMed_Id As Variant
    Dim strGlucose As Variant

    strDate = InsertForm.TextBox1.Value
    strWeight = InsertForm.TextBox2.Value
    strMed_Id = InsertForm.ListBox2.Value
    strGlucose = InsertForm.TextBox3.Value

    ' InsertForm.Show
    Cells.Clear

    'Database path info
    DBFullName = "C:\Users\ND5036832\Downloads\Assignment1234\Sample1.accdb"

    'open the connection
    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
    Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect

    'Create RecordSet
    Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    With Recordset
        'filter Data
        Source = "Insert into Glucose ([Date],Weight, Med_Id,Glucose) values ( " & strDate & "," & strWeight & "," & strMed_Id & "," & strGlucose & ");"
        .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
        'Msgbox " The query:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Source
        'Write field names
        For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
            Range("G1").Offset(0, Col).Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Name
        Next
        'Write recordset
        'Range("G1").Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset Recordset
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit

    Set Recordset = Nothing
    Connection.Close
    Set Connection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim strDate As Date` should not throw an error. Update your question with the real error please.

Comment: Thank you@ Robin Mackenzie    Here the first line itself saying  Dim strDate as Date showing typeMismatch runtime error-13

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `TextBox` contains `Text` (known as a `String`). If you try to put a `String` into a `Date` variable then I'm not surprised you get an error. Try:

```
strDate = CDate(InsertForm.TextBox1.Value)
```

This converts, or *casts* your string to a date. If you don't give it a string  in date format it will, again, throw an error.

---

***Furthermore***. Be careful how you name your variables. `strDate` has "str" at the beginning to remind you that you're dealing with a `String` so you'd expect to see this:

```
Dim strDate As String
```

Since your variable will be in `Date` format, consider renaming it to something like:

```
Dim dtDate As Date
```

Or much better, ignore this *Hungarian* style naming convention and just name it something that has more meaning, like:

```
Dim selectedDate As Date
```

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion - but OP states the error is occurring on `Dim strDate As Date`.... hope your answer works though.

Comment: Yeah agreed the error wouldn't be on that line! OP's code will surely throw a Run-time error '13' on the line corrected in this answer, so I thought it was probably the underlying issue :)

Comment: Your issue is that you never loaded the form Insertform according to your code. So Textbox1.value is empty.

Comment: Hi @UmaDeviNangana, We are not here to debug your code for you. Please search the internet for how to debug your code if you aren't aware of the techniques. Whilst you are here, please also take the time to go back through your other questions and accept the answers which solved your problems. You problem is that you aren't entering a valid date into `TextBox1`, debug it to see what that value is. Once that's sorted I'm sure this answer will also work for you.

Comment: Before your line strDate = InsertForm.TextBox1.Value show the form with Insertform.Show.

Comment: @ CallumDA: I assume OP has an excel file with a form Insertform.